# Download csv file at specific place in JSP

Tags: jsp, csv

I am accessing the database in csv format but I am giving the manual path to save the csv file . But how a user can save this file at their location. And this is web base application.

Code:-

```
public void download() throws SQLException{
        FileWriter writer;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter("/home/auroin/Downloads/java_csv/xyu.csv",false);
            pst = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM Email_Test" );
            while(rs.next()){
                writer.append(rs.getString("Email_Id")); 
                writer.append(",");
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @zvdh, Question is already clear and saying need a location to save the file.

Comment: If you're asking a question, don't you think that you'll get answers much more faster if you describe problem in details? What is your application? Is it web-application or desktop? How do you want to customize location? Do you want to let user select it? Please, desribe problem properly, there are no mind-readers :)

Comment: Now you need to tell us **what kind** of web application... and **where** do you want to save the client? client? server?

Comment: @DavidPostill , it is basically eCommerce web application..

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here are expected to be __specific programming problems__ expressed _clearly_. Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A perfect way to save the file to user's locations:-

```
public void download() throws SQLException{
        FileWriter writer;
        final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(fc); //parent component to JFileChooser
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { //OK button pressed by user
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile(); //get File selected by user
            try {
                writer = new FileWriter(file+"data.csv",false);
                pst = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM Email_Test" );
                while(rs.next()){
                    writer.append(rs.getString("Email_Id")); 
                    writer.append(",");
                }
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm. @RajeevArora you said **Thanku for your answer. But this is a web application.** and then an hour later posted your own answer which seems to use all the bits it needs from my answer... :/

Answer (score -2):

**From a Java Program**

You can use a `JFileChooser`. See [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html):

> File choosers provide a GUI for navigating the file system, and then either choosing a file or directory from a list, or entering the name of a file or directory. To display a file chooser, you usually use the JFileChooser API to show a modal dialog containing the file chooser. Another way to present a file chooser is to add an instance of JFileChooser to a container.

A JFileChooser is a dialog to select a file or files.

The return value of the three methods is one of the following:

- JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION, if the user clicks Cancel.
- JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION, if the user click an OK/Open/Save button.
- JFileChooser.ERROR_OPTION, if the user closes the dialog

A return value of JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION, indicates that you can call its getSelectedFile or getSelectedFiles methods:

```
public java.io.File getSelectedFile()  //  example: user wants to save to this file
public java.io.File[] getSelectedFiles()
```

For an example see [Java Tutorial » Swing » JFileChooser](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/JFileChooser.htm):

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainClass extends JFrame {
  public MainClass() {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose a file");
    this.getContentPane().add(fileChooser);
    fileChooser.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new MainClass();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

**From a JSP Page**

To use a file chooser from a JSP page see [Jsp File Browser](http://www.vonloesch.de/filebrowser.html):

This JSP program allows remote web-based file access and manipulation. Features:

- Create, copy, move, rename and delete files and directories
- Shortkeys
- View Files (pictures, movies, pdf, html,...)
- Javascript filename filter
- Edit textfiles
- Upload files to the server (Status via Upload monitor)
- Download files from the server
- Download groups of files and folders as a single zip file that is created on the fly
- Execute native commands on the server (e.g ls, tar, chmod,...)
- View entries and unpack zip, jar, war and gz files on the server
- Just one file, very easy to install (in fact, just copy it to the server)
- Customizable layout via css file
- Restrict file access via black or whitelist
- Changeable to a read-only (with or without upload) solution

Comment: Thanku for your answer. But this is a web application.

Comment: So why didn't you mention that in the first place?

Comment: Hmm. Why all the downvotes (not just on my own answer)?